# How to represent InverseLaplaceTransform via Fourier transform?

Tags: integral-transforms

I currently use the following code to represent Laplace transform via Fourier transform. It turned to be more powerful. But can I represent inverse Laplace transform in a similar way?

```
I/2 FourierTransform[I t f[I t] Sign[t], t, x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Comment: Is this really a Mathematica question? Isn't it more of a question on the underlying relationship between those two integral transforms?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk but is it possible to just invert the operator in the question?

Comment: Not sure what the question. The Laplace transform contains the Fourier transform by setting the $s=0+i\sigma $. And the inverse Laplace transform has a formula too in terms of a contour integral.